# Necessary to remove ScrollView from Superview before changing and re-adding?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that of course contains information.  Based on conditions I make changes to the height of the scrollview as such:

```
CGRect scrollFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
scrollFrame.size.height = scrollFrame.size.height + adMobBannerView.frame.size.height;
self.scrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

I then add the scrollview back:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

All of this works as it should.  However, should I first be removing the scrollview from the superview before adding it again?  While again what I am doing works, I am wondering if I am just layering scrollviews on top of scrollviews unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add `UIScrollView` as subview after you change its height (if it is currently added as subview).

When you try to add view A as a subview of view B and view A has superview it would be removed from its superview so you don't have to call `removeFromSuperview` method yourself. 
From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:):

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.